# Commutator with x vs commutator with smooth function

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $A$ be an bounded operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ with norm bounded by $1$,
$$
\|A\|_{op}\leq 1.
$$
Suppose that the commutator $[x,A] = xA-Ax$, against the multiplication operator $x$, also
satisfies
$$\|[x,A]\|_{op}\leq 1.
$$

The commutator $[x,A]$ somehow measures how nonlocal the operator $A$ is.  Indeed, if $[x,A]=0$ then one would have that $A$ must be multiplication against some function.

I am interested in whether $[x,A]$ controls commutators of the form $[V,A]$, where $V(x)$ is a Lipschitz function.  More precisely, I would like to know whether it holds that
$$
\|[V,A]\|_{op} \leq \|V\|_{Lip}
$$
given the assumptions above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!